# Why can't I use the Java 7 diamond syntax with a guava ImmutableSortedMap.Builder

Tags: java, java-7, guava, diamond-operator

I'm using java 7 and this snippet doesn't compile

```
ImmutableSortedMap<Integer, String> INT_TO_WORD =
       new ImmutableSortedMap.Builder<>(Ordering.natural())
           .put(1, "one")
           .put(2, "two")
           .put(3, "three")
           .build();
```

whereas this one does

```
ImmutableSortedMap<Integer, String> INT_TO_WORD =
       new ImmutableSortedMap.Builder<Integer, String>(Ordering.natural())
           .put(1, "one")
           .put(2, "two")
           .put(3, "three")
           .build();
```

Why do I need to specify the types on the `rhs` when I have specified them on the `lhs`?
Is there something more to the `<>` operator than meets the eye.

Comment: Java's type inference is limited.  It was improved somewhat in Java 8, but still has some annoying quirks.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Would this work in Java 8?

Comment: @nikhil Nope. Java 8 has the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jeffrey pointed out, Java's type inference has some quirks.  The diamond syntax can be used in place of the full type syntax only when you are calling a constructor of the Object type that you are assigning the variable to.

The reason you CAN'T use the diamond syntax the way you were trying to is because you were using it with the constructor of a **builder object** instead of the **actual final object** that you are assigning the variable to.

So in other words, this works:

```
// Assigning directly to new object
ObjectInterface<Integer, String> object = new ObjectImplementation<>()
```

And this doesn't:

```
// Assigning to the result of a method off of a different object;
// will fail without generic arguments
ObjectInterface<Integer, String> object = new ObjectInterface.Builder<>().build();
```

Java's diamond syntax and generic inference isn't robust enough to figure out what you are doing with the builder, probably because such robustness would be tricky to implement, as java's generic inference would somehow have to know that your "build" method is tied to your builder's generic parameters.

Answer (score 6):

This is different than for instance

```
ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here the `new` on the right hand side is effectively creating the ArrayList.

In your example the `new` is creating a completely different type, namely `Builder` and only in the end an `ImmutableSortedMap` is created by the `build()` method.
The compiler can't know that the Builder<> has anything do to with your ImmutableSortedMap.

Or with a silly example, this could be perfectly valid:

```
ArrayList<String> l = new SomethingSilly<Boolean>().getArrayListOfStrings();
```

Comment: Theoretically, it would be possible to design java to account for the generic parameters returned by `build()` being tied to the generic parameters of `Builder()<A, B>`.  If Java could make this connection, then the "silly example" wouldn't compile.  But, Java doesn't make this connection.

Comment: I think I disagree. The clue of the example is that there IS no connection between the Boolean type of SomethingSilly and the fact that the getArrayListOfStrings returns an ArrayList<String>. I could have several methods in this class, each returning a different typed list, none of them being Boolean. Yet the type argument of the class is Boolean. So there is no way Java could infer what to put between `<>` on the SomethingSilly class.

Comment: Theoretically, if it's coded as `public class SomethingSilly<T> {...public getArrayList() { return new ArrayList()<T> } ... }`, then Java could have been designed to be able to make this inference.
But I see that I didn't look at your "SomethingSilly" example close enough, so yes, you are right, it would still compile because your `getArrayListOfStrings()` isn't tied to the generic parameter of the `SomethingSilly` class.
But @nikhil's example of Builder.build() IS tied to the generic parameters of the class, and so the "SomethingSilly" example is not directly analogous.

Comment: But since Java currently doesn't actually make this inference connection, my point is only theoretical.